# how to disable the multiple class in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to disable all class in button if the specific class is added in the button. I have tried to disable the all class but I made somewhere mistake.

**Jquery:**

```
if ($('.lgi_btn_cta_toggle').hasClass('lgi_cta_inactive')) {
$(this).attr("disabled", true);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button data-action="Hyperlink" class="lgi_btn_cta_add add-sub lgi_btn_cta lgi_cta_inactive clearboth"><span>Hey</span></button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.lgi_btn_cta_remove:after {
  font-family: "MaterialIcons";
  content: "\e14c";
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-width: 43px;
  height: 44px;
  background: #5a9996;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -9px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  border-radius: 50px 18px 18px 50px;
  padding-top: 10px !important;
```

Comment: Use correct selector `$('.lgi_btn_cta_toggle.lgi_cta_inactive').prop("disabled", true)`

Comment: When i have .lgi_cta_inactive class, the button should be disable.

Comment: Simply do `$('.lgi_btn_cta_toggle').removeAttr('class')` and it would remove all the classes.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery <= 1.6

```
$('.lgi_btn_cta.lgi_cta_inactive').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Jquery > 1.6

```
$('.lgi_btn_cta.lgi_cta_inactive').prop('disabled', true);
```